# Angular: Put logged in user id in the payload

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

how can I get the user id that logged in into the system and put the user id in the payload if the user wants to update their data base on their id without the user put their id manually?

- MY LOGIN COMPONENT

  ```
  export class LoginComponent {

  studentForm: FormGroup;
  student: any;

   constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private crudService: CrudService,
    private router: Router,
    private toastr: ToastrService) {

    this.studentForm = this.fb.group({
      id: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });
  }

  saveStudentDetails(values) {
    const studentData = {};

    studentData['id'] =  values.id;
    studentData['password'] =  values.password;

    this.crudService.loginstudent(studentData).subscribe(result => {
      this.student = result;
      this.toastr.success('You are logged in', 'Success !', { positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right' });
      console.log(this.crudService.loginstudent);
      this.router.navigate(['/address']);
    },
      err => {
        console.log('status code ->' + err.status);
        this.toastr.error('Please try again', 'Error !', { positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right' });
   });
  }}
  ```

// MY EDIT COMPONENT

```
saveStudentDetails(values) {
  // const studentData = new FormData();
  const studentData = {};

  studentData['s_pNumber'] =  values.s_pNumber;
  studentData['s_address'] =  values.s_address;
  studentData['s_pCode'] =  values.s_pCode;
  studentData['s_city'] =  values.s_city;
  studentData['s_state'] =  values.s_state;
  studentData['s_country'] =  values.s_country;

  this.crudService.createAddress(studentData).subscribe(result => {
    // this.student = result;
    this.toastr.success('Your data has been inserted', 'Success !', { positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right' });
    // this.router.navigate(['/finance']);
  },
    err => {
      console.log('status code ->' + err.status);
      this.toastr.error('Please try again', 'Error !', { positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right' });
});
```

}

// THIS IS MY SERVICE

```
createAddress(data) {

const postHttpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
};

postHttpOptions['observe'] = 'response';

return this.http.put(this.url + '/address/${id}', data);

}
```

I don't know if I'm doing the right thing, can anyone help me how to include the user id in the payload to be sent to backend? thank you

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Change this
return this.http.put(this.url + '/address/${id}', data);

//to this
   return this.http.put(`${this.url}/address/${id}`, data);

//use the backtick
`
// not this
'
```

[An image showing the backtick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRNXN.png)

Comment: my payload still did not have the user id https://imgur.com/U1nCkps . How can i put the user id in the payload?

Comment: You are using the single quotes instead of backticks